# How to catch error at Mapbox tile request for invalid or expired token

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

We are using mapbox-gl library for to load tiles like bing tile and our internal tiles.

```
 this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: options.mapContainer,
      style: this.getBaseMapStyle(),
      minZoom: options.minZoom,
      maxZoom: options.maxZoom,
      TransformType: ImageryWarehouseTransform,
    });
```

We are passing `tileUrl` to as per our need. But question is how to catch error if access token is invalid or expired.

I checked this but nothing is coming here. Is there something wrong I am doing.

```
map.on('error', () => {
console.log('A error event occurred.');
});
```

Comment: Suggest changing the title and wording of your question to match what it is really about: detecting whether a Mapbox GL access token is invalid or expired. Nothing to do with Bing or tile loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me, catching invalid tokens:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'invalid_token';
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'mapsection', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11' // style URL
});
map.on('error', (response) => {
    alert(response.error.message)
});
```